# Stack Overflow Login Issues

Tags: discussion, facebook

My Stack Overflow account currently login by using my facebook. Then now I am thinking to close my Facebook account. The question is how to change or have my new login id and password to log in Stack Overflow after I close my facebook account. I need to have the same (current) Stack Overflow account, I dont want to create another new one. Is there have any possible way to do that.
Sorry about my question that is totally not related to the code issues, but I have to ask this here because this important to me.

Comment: Also related: [How do I change my OpenID provider(s)?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/793/how-do-i-change-my-openid-providers)

Comment: The referred-to question for the answer may seem different, but it indeed contains the way to add a new login (new email addres + new password). Once that's done, delete the Facebook login.